# Tomcat doesn't log to catalina.out, nor does it create log file I specified

Tags: tomcat, logging, catalina, catalina.out

I've got CentOS 7 installed on my machine (Basic Web Server with Java Servlet Engine - Tomcat), and I have Spring Boot app. If I build my app as a jar, and run it on server with `java -jar my_app.jar`, the app starts fine, and logs to file specified in application.properties (logging.file). But, after converting app to war packaging (using [this tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)), and deploying it to tomcat, app is running but tomcat doesn't log to file I specified, nor does it log in catalina.out

Both catalina.home and catalina.base point to `/usr/share/tomcat/` folder. Also, I can't acces `/usr/share/tomcat/logs` even though I'm admin and using `sudo`. Only thing written in `catalina.out` is: `tomcat-7.0.54 RPM installed`. I've checked that as a root user. Might be permission problem, don't know. Normally, I would use logger to check for problems, but, as I've said, relevant logs are non-existent.

Has anyone expirienced similar issue, or knows the solution?

Comment: Sounds very weird. Tomcat never prints "tomcat-7.0.54 RPM installed" to `catalina.out`, so that came from somewhere else. What happens if you launch Tomcat using `bin/catalina.sh run` instead of `bin/catalina.sh start` or `bin/startup.sh`?

Comment: Sorry, can't answer that question. Since I didn't get any answers or comments I decided to remove Tomcat and deploy my app as a .jar file using systemd. But thanks for trying to help ;)

Comment: Awesome: `systemd` is now a servlet container. Getting better every day.

Comment: I don't know if you are sarcastic or serious but that is not what I said. systemd is not a servlet container (at least I don't think so). I said I used systemd to start my app which is in .jar format (like most of Java apps). Spring Boot .jar files have embedded Tomcat instance. I hope I clarified my previous comment. Kind regards :)